# Why isn't MongoDB installation not working?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

```
MACUSER$ mongod
2015-09-13T22:04:36.395-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
2015-09-13T22:04:36.395-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2015-09-13T22:04:36.395-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Comment: Because you are running under a user that does not have permissions to the temporary file as is exactly reported in the error. Please make sure to follow all of the installation and running instructions as provided: [Install MongoDB on OSX](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Comment: But i'm using admin user

Comment: Please take the time to read the guide and all the related links. Your quick response indicates that you are not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is already be installed. Who's the owner of `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` (`ls -l /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`)?

If that process is owned by someone and you cannot do anything about it, you can run with the `--nounixsocket` option, which will avoid trying to create the socket under /tmp. You can also try [setting `net.unixDomainSocket.pathPrefix`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.unixDomainSocket.pathPrefix) to something else.

Comment: How do I determine who the owner is? I'm the only owner of my macbook pro.

Comment: Then it's likely you're owner. Easiest thing for you is to kill the existing `mongod` process via OS X's Activity Monitor. Note that the `ls` command I put in my comment will list the owner's name followed by the group's name (amongst other things).

Comment: This is what I placed in my terminal:

`MACUSER$ /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock(ls -l /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ls' `

Comment: What I get back is `srwx------  1 root  wheel  0 13 Sep 20:09 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

Comment: So that's owned by [the root user](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012), did you start MongoDB as root? Otherwise that's odd. You can only stop the process as root [using kill](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill). If it's already running why do you need to restart. Just connect by typing `mongo`.

Comment: When I enter `mongo`, I get
`MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: test
2015-09-17T20:20:17.534-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-09-17T20:20:17.536-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed`

Comment: I may have changed directory. db is located under MACUSER/Sites/mongo/data/db